# How to rotate an image before saving to the MediaLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am allowing the user to use the hardware camera button to take a picture, which may be accomplished in either portrait or landscape mode. I noticed, however, that even though my videobrush is rotated accordingly, the captured image it not saved in the MediaLibrary according to the current rotation of the imagebrush. How would I be able to rotate an image on the cameracapturetask_completed event so that I can correct this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use WriteableBitmapEx http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ and use extension methods to rotate the image